# Чим зумовлено вживання флексії -и в родовому відмінку?

Tags: правопис, відмінювання, родовий-відмінок

Дедалі частіше в сучасній публіцистиці знаходжу приклади вживання флексії -и в родовому відмінку, зокрема в Є.Сверстюка: "індивідуальности", в О.Забужко: "смерти", "самодостатности". Чим це зумовлено? Адже завжди вважала, що тут використовуємо закінчення -і.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Скоріш такі люди є прихильниками досовітського письма, яке було затверджено наступними документами:

[Класичний правопис — 1928](https://r2u.org.ua/node/231)

> #### § 25. В родовому відмінку однини іменники мають закінчення ‑а (‑я), ‑у (‑ю), ‑и (‑яти, ‑ати, ‑ени), ‑і (‑ї).
>
> **4. ‑и** мають:
>
> **а)** Усі іменники жіночого роду тверді (див. § 22 і відміна 1 гр.): *коло вод**и́***, *без кни́жк**и***…
>
> **б)** Іменники жіночого роду 3 відм. (див. § 22) на **‑ть** за другим приголосним: *від ра́дост**и***, *з ві́ст**и***, *до сме́рт**и***, *без чве́рт**и***…
>
> Також винятково: *до о́сен**и***, *без со́л**и***, *кро́в**и***, *любо́в**и***, *Ру́с**и***.
>
> **в)** Усі іменники ніякого роду з наростками **-ят-** (після **ж**, **ч**, **ш**, **щ** **‑ат‑** — див. § 22 2 відміна): *до теля́т**и***, *горща́т**и***… і слово *і́мен**и***.

[Правопис](//zbruc.eu/node/66463) на основі [Желехівки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) — 1892

> част-ь
> **част-и**
> част-и
> част-ь
> част-е
> части-ю (частю)
> част-и

[Проєкт 1999](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/69.html)

> У родовому відмінку однини іменники III відміни на **-ть** за другим приголосним кореня (основи), а також слова *кров, любов, осінь, сіль, Русь, Білору́сь*, мають закінчення **-и**: *ві́сти, незале́жности, ра́дости, сме́рти, че́сти; кро́ви, любо́ви, о́сени, со́ли, Ру́си, Білору́си*. Усі инші іменники мають закінчення **-і**: *бо́язні, га́лузі, но́чі, о́сі, пе́чі, по́дорожі, ті́ні, ста́лі* та ин.

---

Також цього дозволяє [правопис 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=100)
року:

> Іменники на **-ть** після приголосного, а також слова *кров, любо́в, о́сінь, сіль, Русь, Білору́сь* у родовому відмінку однини можуть набувати як варіант закінчення **-и**: *гід́ности, незале́жности, ра́дости, сме́рти, че́сти, хоро́брости; кро́ви, любо́ви, о́сени, со́ли, Ру́си́, Білору́си.*

Comment: Тобто закінчення -и вмотивовано історією українського правопису і є більш правильним у використанні..?

Comment: @Анна1989, ну, що є «більш правильним», вирішує кожен сам для себе. Це було однією з особливостей напрямку розвитку української мови до 1930-х років, допоки його було примусово змінено. Шкода, що тоді творилося таке — але сам лише факт того, що щось було змінено примусово, не обов'язково означає, що **кожен** аспект попереднього напрямку був кращим. Хоча ймовірність, звісно, велика. Однак сучасний правопис такі закінчення все ще не почав визнавати.

Answer (score 4):

Згідно з [сучасним офіційним українським правописом](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf) (зміни від 2019 року) можливі обидва варіанти: `Незалежности` та `Незалежності`. Докладніше з правопису:

> У родовому та давальному відмінках однини іменники третьої відміни
> мають закінчення -і: *Бе́ршаді, вані́лі, га́лузі, гера́ні, гі́дності,
> кро́ві, любо́ві, мо́ці, незале́жності, не́хворощі, но́чі, Оболо́ні,
> о́сені, о́сі, по́дорожі, при́язні, ре́чі, Ру́сі́, со́лі, ста́лі,
> су́міші, ті́ні, У́мані, фа́льші, флане́лі, хоро́брості*.
>
> Іменники на
> -ть після приголосного, а також слова *кров, любо́в, о́сінь, сіль, Русь, Білору́сь* у родовому відмінку однини можуть набувати як варіант
> закінчення -и: *гі́дности, незале́жности, ра́дости, сме́рти, че́сти,
> хоро́брости; кро́ви, любо́ви, о́сени, со́ли, Ру́си́ , Білору́си*.

Answer (score 2):

**Коротко:** так історічнїше і лӧґічнїше.

[Проблеми українського правопису в 20 столітті](//r2u.org.ua/node/126) · [Василь Німчук](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> Нині найбільші суперечки в середовищі фахівців і ширшої громадськості ведуться навколо флексій родового відмінка однини іменників третьої відміни та слів четвертої відміни з суф. **-ен-**.
>
> В академічних «Найголовніших правилах...» встановлено норму: «У словах жіночого роду, що кінчаються на приголосний звук, треба писати в родовому відмінкові однини **-и**, а в давальному й місцевому однини та називному й знахідному множини треба писати **-і**; напр., род. відм. — *з ночи*, *коло печи*, *з подорожи*, *цієї соли*, *нічної тіни*, *без сповіди*, *без відповіди*, *з радости*, *до смерти*... Виняток в *осени*” (с. 9). Таке ж правило було і в проекті УП 26: “**-и** мають ... б) Усі речівники жіночого роду на приголосний ...: *з радости*, *без подорожи*, *до ночи*, *від розкоши*, *крови*, *твари*, *молоди*, *поморози*, *соли*, *тіни*, *Роси*, *артіли*, *морали*, *матери* ...” Тут же сказано, що **-и** мають “усі речівники ніякого роду з наростками **-ят** (після **ж**, **ч**, **ш**, **щ** **-ат-**), **-ен-**: *до теляти*, *горщати*... і слово *імени*” (с. 35).
>
> [УП 28](//r2u.org.ua/node/231) правило щодо флексії родового відмінка однини іменників жіночого роду третьої відміни дає трохи інші рекомендації: “**-и** мають <...> б) Іменники жіночого роду III відм. ... на **-ть** за другим приголосним: *від радости*, *з вісти*, *до смерти*, *без чверти* ... Також винятково: *до осени*, *без соли*, *крови*, *любови*, *Руси*” (с. 35). Стосовно іменників середнього роду сказано, що в родовому однини **-и** приймають слова “з наростками **-ят** (після **ж**, **ч**, **ш**, **щ** **-ат-**...): *до теляти*, *горщати* ... і слово *імени*” (с. 35).
>
> [УП 33](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1933_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) (*моя прим.*: совʼєтський) скасував це правило щодо іменників III відміни: “Родовий, давальний відм. має закінчення **-і** (с. 41): *вісті*, *тіні*, *подорожі*” (с. 31, таблиця), яке діє понині. Проте УП 33 залишає флексію **-и** формі у назв середнього роду з суф. **–ен**”: *імени* (с. 42).
>
> Історично іменники III відміни колишньої **-і**-основи в родовому відмінку однини мали флексію **-и**: *ночи* і под. За аналогією до них закінчення **-е** було витіснене флексією **-и** в родовому відмінку іменників колишніх **-u-** (**-ъv-**)-основ: *свекърве* — *свекърви*. Іменники колишніх **-і-** та **-u**-основ стійко зберігали флексію **-и** на всій українській етнічній території. Лише в другій половині XVII ст. в актах з терену Гетьманщини зрідка фіксується закінчення **-ѣ** (тобто **-і**) в результаті впливу іменників колишньої **-ja**-основи (*земля* — *землѣ* > *земл’і*): *з Березанѣ*, *прошу милостѣ*, *кровѣ*, *любовѣ* (Пирятинські акти {Самійленко С.П. Нариси з історичної морфології української мови. – К., 1964. - Ч. 1. - С. 146}). Панівною і на цих теренах залишалася флексія **-и**: *речы*, *пам’яти* (Бориспільські акти), *любови*, *корысты*, *отповѣди* (Полтавські акти), *для памяти* (Пирятинські акти) {Самійленко С.П. Нариси з історичної морфології української мови. – К., 1964. - Ч. 1. - С. 145}. Пор. ще 1583 p. в Житомирській актовій книзі: *на запя(ст)ю троха продрано до крывѣ* {Актова книга Житомирського міського уряду кінця XVI ст. (1582—1588 рр.) / Підгот. до видання М.К.Бойчук. — К., 1965. — С. 69}, але там же: *на вчине(н)е справедливости єго мл(с)ти* та ін.
>
> У XIX ст. стійко зберігалася флексія **-и**. Полтавець І.Котляревський вживає тільки давню флексію: И **солы** крымкы и бахмуткы; Въ отравлену ѣu утробу Наклала **злосты**, мовъ бы бобу; Къ Лависи одъ **любвы** бувъ въ гори; Позволь тила убытой **раты**, Як водится, земли предаты; Летыть Трояньцивъ обозрыты, Роздуть въ ныхъ **храбросты** огонь {Виргилиева Энеида, на малороссийский язык переложенная И.Котляревским. - Харьков, 1842. - Ч. II. - С. 9; Ч. IV. - С. 27, 37;Ч. V. - С. 28; Ч. VI. - С. 46-74}.
>
> Основоположник новоукраїнської літературної мови Т.Шевченко, до якого так часто апелюють «ревнителі» української мови, котрим у всьому незвичному або неприйнятному для них увижаються підступи галичан і діаспори, вживав у третій відміні тільки споконвічну флексію **-и** (графічно, за російською системою — **-ы**) в родовому однини та називному відмінку множини іменників третьої відміни: *Пошли тоби Матер-божа Тіи **благодаты** Всего того, чого маты Не зуміе даты; Безъ **сповиды** святои умирають; Гуляючи якъ той казавъ Шматокъ хлиба ззucmы Иды жъ доню, а ты сыну, Послухаешъ висты* {Шевченко Т. Три літа / Автографи поезій 1843—1845 років. — К., 1966. - C. 15, 62, 54}.
>
> У частині говорів української мови ішов процес вирівнювання флексій іменників за першою відміною, за якою змінювалась абсолютна більшість слів жіночого роду.
>
> До початку XX ст. процес витіснення флексії **-и** через **-і** в говірках південно-східного й частково північного наріччя української мови зайшов досить далеко в іменників, основи яких закінчуються не на групи приголосних, тому граматисти — вихідці з цих діалектних ареалів не подають одноманітної флексії в родовому відмінку однини іменників третьої відміни. Наприклад, Є.Тимченко подає: *реч**-і*** (*річі*), *тін**и*** (*тіні*), части, вдячности матери {Тимченко Є. Українська граматика. — К., 1907. - Ч. 1. — C. 113— 114}. Б.Грінченко в своєму букварі «Українська граматика до науки читання й писання» (Київ, 1907, 1917) у родовому відмінку однини іменників третьої відміни поруч із флексією **-і** вживає **-и**: *мудрости*, *смерти*, *соли* {Статєєва В. Українські письменники про проблеми літературної мови та мовознавства кінця XIX — початку XX ст. — Ужгород, 1997. - С.244}. М.Гладкий у парадигмі третьої відміни в родовому однини фіксує форми: *печі*, *тіні*, *матері*, але *части*, *свідомости*, *любови* {Гладкий М. Практический курс украинского языка для учительских семинарий, учительских курсов и старших классов средних учебных заведений. — Житомир, 1918. — C. 33}.
>
> М.Грунський та Г.Сабалдир у “зразках деклінації речівників жіночого роду” подають у родовому відмінку однини іменників третьої відміни: *вдячности*, але *податі*, *ночі*, *речі* {Грунський М., Сабалдир Г. Практичний російсько-український словник ділової мови. - К., 1924. — C. 165}.
>
> Найповнішу картину поширення флексій **-и** або **-і** в українських говорах нині дає Атлас української мови. У ньому скартографовано тільки форми лексем *сіл'* та *ніч* у першому томі (“Полісся, Середня Наддніпрянщина і суміжні землі”) та слів *сіл'*, *ніч*, *л'убоў* у другому (Волинь, Наддністрянщина, Закарпаття і суміжні землі). На жаль, тут немає зовсім матеріалів про форми родового відмінка однини іменників із суфіксом **-ість** та інших слів третьої відміни, котрі мають у кінці групу приголосних (наприклад, *кiс'т'*, *мас'т'*).
>
> На території першого тому Атласу української мови північну межу поширення форм родового відмінка *соли* на Лівобережжі можна окреслити приблизно так: північніше від c. Сувид Вишгородського р-ну — c. Козари Носівського р-ну Чернігівської обл. — м. Ніжин Чернігівської — c. Обмачів Бахмацького р-ну Чернігівськ. обл., далі — на південь від р. Сейм. На Правобережжі форма *соли* функціонує то в ширшій, то вужчій смузі вздовж за течією Дніпра та на північ від Дністра. У багатьох говірках форма *соли* функціонує паралельно з формою *сол'і* {Атлас української мови. — Т. 1: Полісся, Середня Наддніпрянщина і суміжні землі. — К., 1984. — Карта № 190}.
>
> Форма *ночи* поширена на Правобережжі на північ від умовної лінії: нижче м. Бердичева Житомирської обл. — м. Фастів та Васильків Київської обл., на Лівобережжі: від c. Хоцьки Переяслав-Хмельницького р-ну Київської обл. на північний схід — південніше м. Прилук Чернігівської обл. — на захід від м. Ромни Сумської обл. - на захід від м. Конотоп цієї обл. — на північ від р. Сейм у межах Сумської обл. {Атлас української мови. — Т. 1: Полісся, Середня Наддніпрянщина і суміжні землі. — К., 1984. — Карта № 190}.
>
> В ареалах, охоплених другим томом Атласу української мови, панівними є форми на **-и** в родовому відмінку іменників жіночого роду на приголосний: *соли*, *тіни*, *ночи*, *л'убови* (*л'убви*), причому форми типу *ночи*, *л'убови* (*л'убви*) засвідчуються в далеко більшій кількості говірок, ніж форми *coли* {Атлас української мови. — Т. 2: Волинь, Наддністрянщина, Закарпаття і суміжні землі. — К., 1988. — Карти № 174—175}.
>
> Дослідник полтавських говорів В.С.Ващенко твердив, що в них варіантність флексій **-и** та **-і** спостерігається в записах живої мови XIX ст., але в записах середини XX ст. закінчення **-і** переважає й “помічається тенденція до звуження обсягу застосування форми на **-и**. Можливо, що таке звуження відбувається під впливом літературної норми” {Ващенко В.C. Полтавські говори. — Харків, 1957. — С. 107—108; Самійленко С.П. Нариси з історичної морфології української мови. – К., 1964. - Ч. 1. - С. 146—147)}. Очевидно, флексія **-і** витісняє **-и** в родовому відмінку іменників жіночого роду на приголосний під впливом літературної мови (навчання в школі!) і на інших теренах України. (*моя прим.:* 1876 — [ярижка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7))
>
> Для збереження традиції чіткішої диференціації флексій іменників третьої відміни (адже тепер однакові флексії вони мають у родовому, давальному, місцевому відмінках однини й називному та знахідному множини), для розширення стильових можливостей необхідно зберегти, відновити як нормативне закінчення **-и**, визначивши чіткі правила його застосування. Тут є дві змоги — вернутися до УП 28 або рекомендувати паралельні флексії **-і** та **-и**: *вісті* — *вісти*, *радості* — *радости*, *ночі* — *ночи*, *солі* — *соли* і т. д., адже нині нормативними є паралельні флексії відповідно дві в давальному (*робітникові* — *робітнику*) й три в місцевому (*на робітнику*, *робітниці*, *робітникові*) відмінках однини в іменників чоловічого роду другої відміни. У кожному разі дозволити вживання флексії **-и** в словах із основою на групу приголосних в художній літературі, як це було прийнято більшістю голосів на одному з засідань Національної правописної комісії, — наполовину розв’язати проблему. Велика частина органів масової інформації вже нині широко вживає флексію **-и** в родовому відмінку однини іменників третьої відміни з основою (коренем) на групу приголосних та в словах *сіль*, *осінь*, *кров*, *любов*, *Русь* (пор. офіційний титул *Патріарх Київський і всієї України-Руси*). Цю практику треба узаконити, тобто повернутися до норми правопису 1928 р.
>
> Староукраїнські пам’ятки документовують тільки закінчення **-и**, **-е** в іменників середнього роду колишніх **-n**-основ: *имени* і под. {Самійленко С.П. Іменник // Історія української мови: Морфологія. - К., 1978. - С. 121}. Нам не відомі факти засвідчення в старовинних текстах форм із флексією **-і** (**-ѣ**) в іменах **-n**-основи. В І.Котляревського читаємо:
>
> > Пославъ послами до Латына
> >     Одъ *имены* свого и чына
> >     {Виргилиева Энеида... — Ч. IV. — С. 22}.
>
> М.Гладкий у парадигмі лексеми *ім’я* в родовому однини подає форми *ім’я*, *імени* {Гладкий M. Зазнач. праця. — С. 29}.
>
> Лише в другому томі Атласу української мови скартографовано форми родового відмінка однини іменників колишньої **-n**-основи. У них, як правило, збігаються форми родового відмінка однини з називним. Тільки в небагатьох поселеннях засвідчено як основні форми типу *виме'ні*, *с'імен'і*, *т'імени*, *імен'і*. Частіше вони виступають як паралельні до форм типу *імйа* (*імн'а*). Лише в поодиноких поселеннях Правобережжя відзначено форму *імени* {Атлас української мови. — Т. 2. — Карта № 207}. Це, напевне, є наслідком впливу літературної мови, зокрема надто поширених у час тоталітаризму найменуваннями заводів, колгоспів, організацій, закладів іменами видатних діячів культури, науки, освіти та, особливо, радянських функціонерів, де форма родового відмінка однини відповідного іменника ніколи не збігалася з формою називного однини: кінотеатр імені Т.Шевченка, консерваторія імені Лисенка і ніколи колгосп ім’я Т.Шевченка і под.
>
> Вважаємо, що треба повернути норми 1927 і 1933 p., вживати *імени* і под., і таким чином усі іменники четвертої відміни в родовому відмінку однини матимуть одну, без винятків, флексію **-и**: *дитяти*, *імени* тощо. За повернення флексії -**и** в родовому відмінку однини іменникам колишньої **-n**-основи висловився недавно акад. Ю.Шевельов {Шевельов Ю. Про критерії в питаннях українського офіційного правопису // Березіль. — 1995. — № 7—10. — С. 165}.